# In Hahn Banach separation theorem, can I restrict separation constant to be 1?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I want to know the following version of the H-B separation theorem.

> If $X$ is a real Banach space and $A, B$ are nonempty convex subsets of $X$ such that $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact, then there exist $x^*\in X^*$, $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^*(a)<\lambda<x^*(b)$ $\forall a\in A,b\in B$.

By considering $\frac{x^*}{\lambda}$, we can set $\lambda=1$, is there any other requirements for this?

Comment: No there aren't.

Comment: You also need to allow $0$. But you can always normalise the situation to have $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda = 1$, if you don't care about whether $x^{\ast}(a) < x^{\ast}(b)$ or $x^{\ast}(b) < x^{\ast}(a)$. If you keep the order requirement, you must allow $\lambda \in \{ 1,0,-1\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean $A, B$ should contains $0$? I don't get it @@

Comment: Sorry, got my geometry mixed up. $0$ can always be avoided if one set is compact and the other closed. But unless you allow the ordering of $x^{\ast}(A)$ and $x^{\ast}(B)$ to be flipped, you must allow $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously you need $\lambda\ne 0$. Or, more precisely, you need to show that, if there are a functional $x^*$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ such that $x^*(a)<\lambda<x^*(b)$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$, then there are a functional $\widehat x$ and $\widehat \lambda\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\widehat x(a)<\widehat \lambda <\widehat x(b)$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

This follows from the fact that $B$ is compact: since $x^*$ is continuous, it has a *minimum* $\min_{b\in B} x^*(b)$ on $B$. Suppose that, by any chance, the functional satisfies $x^*(a)<0<x^*(b)$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$. Since  $x^*(b)>0$ for all $b\in B$, $$\min_{b\in B}x^*(b)>0$$

Therefore, we can observe that $$\forall a\in A,\forall b\in B,\ x^*(a)<\frac12\min_{v\in B}x^*(v)< x^*(b)$$

Thus, given a $x^*$ and a $\lambda$ as in the theorem, either $\lambda\ne0$ (in which case $\widehat x=x^*$ and $\widehat\lambda=\lambda$ work) or $\lambda=0$, in which case $\widehat x=x^*$ and $\widehat\lambda =\frac12\min_{b\in B} x^*(b)$ work.